# Import csv issue (product.php on line 1407)

Tags: product, error, import, csv

I just install the magento 1.9.2 and try to import my csv file through **System -> Import - > Import**.

I received the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: _attribute_set  in /app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php on line 1407
```

everything worked fine with the 1.9.1

Here is the code in line 1407 and 1408

```
if (!is_null($rowData[self::COL_ATTR_SET])) {
    $previousAttributeSet = $rowData[Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::COL_ATTR_SET];
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051916/undefined-index-attribute-set-in-magento-product-csv-import-from-admin may help.. just make sure that you to fill each field with a meaningful value

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the Attribute set value in all rows (keep the header : **_attribute_set**), it fixed the issue for me.